# How can I keep a winrt voip app alive and reachable in connected standby?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, voip

We have a Dell Venue pro tablet and we created a webrtc-based voip app for it. The app is made with C#.

When the device is on, everything works fine. But when it goes in sleep-mode (it has connected standby), it becomes unreachable by our server. The app has a keep-alive trigger, a control-channel trigger and network-state-changed trigger.
We followed [this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj710181.aspx) to try and make it run in the background.

We also downloaded the example provided with this guide. Both our app and the example do not receive any network packets while the device is in sleep-mode. Every 15 minutes the keep-alive trigger is fired and if we let the server send something at the moment it arrives in the app, but about a minute later, packets we send don't arrive anymore.

We tried the following things to see what is going on:
- We tried installing the provided example's server on a remote device. We put the client in sleep-mode and waited for a few minutes and sent a packet. The packet never arrived at the client.
- We tried the skype app. The skype app has the same problem as the example.
- Our own app has the same problem as the example, this was to be expected because it uses the same code.
- We tried another app we have that sends a push notification. The push notification does not arrive at the client if it is in sleep-mode.